# How to skip iterations in a loop?

Tags: python

I have a loop going, but there is the possibility for exceptions to be raised inside the loop. This of course would stop my program all together. To prevent that, I catch the exceptions and handle them. But then the rest of the iteration runs even though an exception occurred. Is there a keyword to use in my `except:` clause to just skip the rest of the current iteration?

Comment: Don't see how the accepted answer (use `continue`) catches exceptions, but it was accepted.  Therefore, the question is really, really confusing.

Comment: @S.Lott I don't need the keyword to catch the exception, i was just talking about the general flow of the total code.

Comment: @The.Anti.9.  What?  First you said "I want to catch the exceptions".  Now you're saying "I don't need the keyword to catch the exception".  Could you clarify this in some way?

Comment: @S.Lott. I don't need to catch the exception with the keyword, there just has to be a try, except statement in the code....

Answer (score 508, accepted):

You are looking for [`continue`](https://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops).

Answer (score 66):

```
for i in iterator:
    try:
        # Do something.
        pass
    except:
        # Continue to next iteration.
        continue
```

Answer (score 56):

**Example for Continue:**

```
number = 0

for number in range(10):
   number = number + 1

   if number == 5:
      continue    # continue here

   print('Number is ' + str(number))

print('Out of loop')
```

**Output:**

```
Number is 1
Number is 2
Number is 3
Number is 4
Number is 6 # Note: 5 is skipped!!
Number is 7
Number is 8
Number is 9
Number is 10
Out of loop
```

Answer (score 23):

Something like this?

```
for i in xrange( someBigNumber ):
    try:
        doSomethingThatMightFail()
    except SomeException, e:
        continue
    doSomethingWhenNothingFailed()
```

Comment: Edited to use continue rather than pass.

Answer (score 17):

I think you're looking for [continue](http://www.network-theory.co.uk/docs/pytut/breakandcontinueStatements.html)

Answer (score 9):

For this specific use-case using `try..except..else` is the cleanest solution, the `else` clause will be executed if no exception was raised.

NOTE: The `else` clause must follow all `except` clauses

```
for i in iterator:
    try:
        # Do something.
    except:
        # Handle exception
    else:
        # Continue doing something
```