# Python 3: skipping to next iteration if condition is not fulfilled - loop in loop

Tags: python-3.x, loops, iteration

I have a loop in a loop like following:

```
iGen = (i for i in range(1,10))
for i in iGen:
   for j in range(1,10):
      some operations
      if certain operation not fulfilled:
         next(iGen)
```

So for example if `i = 5` and the condition is not fulfilled then the `j` loop should be canceled and `i` should iterate to 6.

However, this does not work. Anyone have a suggestion why this logic would be faulty?
Here is the real code. The pseudocode above is just to make the logic clearer.

```
array = [];
for k in range(1, 20):
    y=2**k*(2**(k+1)-1)
    array.append(y)

iGen = (i for i in range(0, len(array)))
for i in iGen:
    x = 1
    for j in range(2, array[i]):
        if array[i] % j == 0:
            g = x
            x = x + j
            if x / g < 2:
                next(iGen)

    if x == array[i]:
        print(array[i])
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/549674/skipping-iterations-in-python ?

Comment: Hey @Jerrybibo continue would iterate j and not i am I right? I however want to iterate i.

Comment: No i just tried it and you are right! This solved my Problem!! Thanks

Comment: As an aside, you can replace `(i for i in range(0, len(array)))` with `range(0, len(array))`. No need for the wrapping generator.

Comment: Yes already did this, but thanks for saying it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use a break.  This will break out of your j-loop and continue on with the next item in the i-loop.

```
iGen = (i for i in range(1,10))
for i in iGen:
   for j in range(1,10):
      some operations
      if certain operation not fulfilled:
         break
```

Comment: Just about to answer this! `next` is just for retrieving the next item. It doesn't stop the logic flow.

Comment: Yes thank you. Or you could use continue just like Jerrybibo suggested.

Comment: @OcK, a continue would continue with the next item in the j-loop.  a break would continue with the next item in the i-loop.

Comment: absolutely correct, I was just testing it and wanted to add it, Thanks for clarifying!!

Comment: Yep, no problem.  Thanks!