# Next element in a for

Tags: python, for-loop

I need to go to the next element of my for if a certain condition is true and restart my cycle from that element.

```
sets = [0,1,2,3]

for elem in sets:
    if (elem == 0)
       #next elem?

    ....
    ....
```

Comment: `continue` stops processing the current element and moves onto the next one, if that's what you are after. The question is not exactly clear.

Comment: there is nothing you have to do to go to the next element. The loop automatically iterates when the nested code has finished executing. To **force** the loop to iterate even if the nested block has not finished executing yet, you can use `continue`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Skipping Iterations in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/549674/skipping-iterations-in-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing you have to do to go to the next element. The loop automatically iterates when the nested code has finished executing.

> Example:

```
for elem in sets:
    if elem == 0:
       print(element)
```

will print all the elements that meet the condition; the `sets` will be exhausted.

---

Now, to **force** the loop to iterate even if the nested block has not finished executing yet, you can use `continue`.

> Example:

```
for elem in sets:
    if elem == 0:
       print('found a 0!')
       continue
    print('Do you see me?')
```

In this case, whenever a `0` is found, the loop will terminate prematurely (without the `'Do you see me?'` being print).

Answer (score 1):

You can use generator :

> Generators functions allow you to declare a function that behaves like
>   an iterator, i.e. it can be used in a for loop.
>
> generator function don't start execution at the beginning of the
>   function. Instead, the new call to a generator function will resume
>   execution right after the yield statement in the code, where the last
>   call exited.

```
your_list=[0,1,0,3]
def condition_loop(x):
    for i in x:
        if i==0:
            yield i
        else:
            yield 'x'

gen=condition_loop(your_list)
for i in range(len(your_list)):
    print(gen.__next__())
```

output:

```
0
x
0
x
```

Answer (score 0):

Use continue:

```
for elem in sets:
    if (elem == 0):
       continue
```

https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops

Answer (score 0):

`continue` could be a solution but you maybe do not need any thing :

```
>>> sets = [0,1,2,3]
>>> for elem in sets:
...     if (elem == 0):
...             print "the 0 element", elem
...     else:
...             print "other element", elem
... 
the 0 element 0
other element 1
other element 2
other element 3
```

Your `for` loop iterate trough all element of you list, `if/elif/else` condition maybe sufficient