# Avoid nested if function and skip line of codes

Tags: python

I have a combination of functions, the code in python has the following format. In the code i am looping over an SQL Table where I always check a key, which get filled with done, after I run the function. So for example I have the "QUEUE_TEST" table which keys:

```
Key Status
A  Pending
B  Pending
C  Pending
```

Then with this Key I load specific data in the function and  I have a new dataframe

```
def main():
 try:
     cursor.execute("SELECT TOP 1 KEY FROM MODEL_FACTORY#PYTHON.QUEUE_TEST 
         WHERE STATUS = 'Pending'")
     result = pd.DataFrame(cursor.fetchone()) 
  while not result.empty:
   input_data = ....


   try:
      if conditionA=True:
        if conditionB=True
        Test
     
      if condtionC=True:
        if conditionD=False:
   except Exception as e
  return
 except Exception as e:
  return
```

How Can I Skip the line of codes after test, If the conditionB is True before Test and start at the while function again? So for example if condition B is True i want to have the following code:

```
def main():
 try:
     cursor.execute("SELECT TOP 1 KEY FROM MODEL_FACTORY#PYTHON.QUEUE_TEST 
         WHERE STATUS = 'Pending'")
     result = pd.DataFrame(cursor.fetchone()) 
  while not result.empty:
   input_data = ....


   try:
      if conditionA=True:
        if conditionB=True
        Test
     
     
   except Exception as e
  return
 except Exception as e:
  return
```

And If conditionB is not True, i want to run the following code:

```
ef main():
 try:
     cursor.execute("SELECT TOP 1 KEY FROM MODEL_FACTORY#PYTHON.QUEUE_TEST 
         WHERE STATUS = 'Pending'")
     result = pd.DataFrame(cursor.fetchone()) 
  while not result.empty:
   input_data = ....


   try:
      if conditionA=True:
        
     
      if condtionC=True:
        if conditionD=False:
   except Exception as e
  return
 except Exception as e:
  return
```

I Know I can do it with if else functions, but as I have a lot of other code after the condition B I would love not to use these kind of format...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to skip iterations in a loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/549674/how-to-skip-iterations-in-a-loop)

Comment: Please provide working MRE, and expected and actual behaviour.

Comment: use Pass keyword inside conditionB

Comment: You can try using elif unstead of if for your next section

Comment: That "example" is really hard to read

Comment: Can you please correct and verify your code and indentation. Is `Test` a method?

Answer (score 4):

You could use `continue` which skips the remaining code inside a loop (for the current iteration only):

```
def main():
 try: 
  while not result.empty:
   try:
      if conditionA=True:
        if conditionB=True
        Test
        continue
      if condtionC=True:
        if conditionD=False:
   except Exception as e
  return
 except Exception as e:
  return
```

Answer (score 2):

I think `elif` would fix your probleme there.

```
def main():
  try:
    while not result.empty:
     if conditionA and conditionB:
       Test
     elif conditionC and not conditionD:
       pass
  except Exception as e:
    return
```

For simplicity I grouped the If-Statements, but the if else should also work, when splitting those.

Just saw other answers using `continue`, those might be better, depends on what you want to achieve in the end.

A comment hinted me, that `!condition` is not valid syntax in python. Thx <3

Comment: You can simplify else if with elif in python

Comment: `not` in Python, not `!`.

Comment: @chipauris it's not just to simplify, `else if` is not a valid syntax.

Answer (score 1):

def main():
try:
while not result.empty:
try:
if conditionA and conditionB:

```
            if conditionC and not conditionD:

        except Exception as e:

except Exception as e:
```